# Python: Comparing two strings that should be the same but that are not

Tags: python, string

I'm a noob so I hope this is the right place to ask this question. This is really driving me nuts. I'm looking for a sentence in some text file, here is the partial code:

```
SentenceIMLookingfor='blha blha blah'
with open('textfile.lua','r') as my_file:
    raw_dadat=my_file.read().split('\n')
    for i in range(1, len(raw_dadat)):
        if(raw_dadat[i]==SentenceIMLookingfor):
          DO_SOMETHING
```

Well it doesn't do anything.( And I need to know at what line "SentenceIMLookingfor" is).
I've check the ids ( ofc they are not the same so if I use 'is' instead of '==' it won't work). Also I'm sure that the sentence is in my text file, it is even stored in raw_data[210]. I've check the "type" and it's str. Also there are about 3 spaces in the sentence, I don't know if that can help, and "len(raw_dadat)" is more or less equal to  4000.
Well I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Did you try printing out what raw_datat[i] is to try and debug this?

Comment: There is probably some punctuation, trailing or leading spaces or something else not causing an exact match to occur.  I would loop through the strings and add some delimiters to check this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely that extra spacing is your culprit.  You may also try downcasing the string.

```
SentenceIMLookingfor='blha blha blah'
with open('textfile.lua','r') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if line.lower().strip() == SentenceIMLookingfor:
            #DO_SOMETHING
```

If, however, you are not checking for a line that is **exactly** equal to the Sentence you're looking for, you'll want to use the `in` operator to check for equality, so replace the `if` above with

```
        if SentenceIMLookingfor in line.lower(): # you may not want .lower()
```

Since there is no need to read the entire file into memory, you can iterate over the lines of the file with `for line in my_file`.  `.lower()` converts a string to all lower-case letters, `.strip()` cuts off any preceding or trailing whitespace

---

As suggested by @SethMMorton in the comments, you can use `enumerate` to iterate with the line numbers `for i, line in enumerate(my_file)`

If you are trying to collect the line numbers that this string appears on (which seems likely) you can accomplish that with a list comprehension

```
with open('textfile.lua','r') as my_file:
    line_nos = [i for i, line in enumerate(my_file) if line.lower().strip() == SentenceIMLookingfor]
```

Comment: Since the OP needs to know the line it is on, perhaps `for i, line in enumerate(my_file):` would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Also, be aware that if you are comparing to a null terminated string, they can appear to be the same value when printed but one may be null terminated and the other not.  So, if you're seeing two strings that appear to be the same but are not, make sure you've put in the null terminator.

```
null_term_str_compare = "123456789012345\0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could obtain a line of your text in the file as a string, and then get this:

```
>>> a = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl"
>>> "qwerty" in a
True
>>>
```

Then turn it into an if statement

```
mySentence = "hello"
for line in file:
    if mySentence in line:
        # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have provided it works for me. Are you sure that you are including the string you wish to find in the target file?

Also Python counts from 0. Did you mean to start your range from 1. If your search term is the first line in the file you will not find it using your code.

The following is a slightly cleaner version of your code (notice that instead of iterating over a range I simply iterate over the lines in the file). I have tested this and it works too.

```
SentenceIMLookingfor='blha blha blah'
with open('textfile.lua','r') as my_file:
    raw_dadat=my_file.read().split('\n')
    for line in raw_dadat:
        if SentenceIMLookingfor in line:
            print "Found"
            print "Line: {0}".format(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed the spacing. To get it to work I slightly change my condition if to this:

```
if(raw_dadat[i].strip()==SentenceIMLookingfor.strip()):
```

And it worked! Thanks a lot to all of you!( Also for the extra advices).